# Visual Studio displays light brown/beige line in git changes/diff

Tags: git, visual-studio, diff

I've been using git within Visual Studio 2017 for my version control and it generally works fairly well.

Most of the time, when viewing changes that I have made, my code is highlighted in red to indicate code removed and green to indicate code added.

However occasionally I get a change I have made highlighted in light-brown/beige.

Can anyone inform me why this is?

A link to the screenshot of this is included below, unfortunately StackOverflow will not let me add an image until I improve my reputation :|

[visual studio brown/beige line on git changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUG8Y.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beige highlighting indicates that a bookmark has been placed on that line.

Bookmarks can be toggled on/off by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>.

Comment: Or maybe a `bookmark` - At least in my case.  
`CTRL + K, CTRL + K` - is used for bookmarks in code.  
The breakpoints are highlighted in red

Comment: Cheers @mihkov, I often get those two mixed up